# Firefox - updating window.location.hash on scroll with jQuery waypoints

Tags: javascript, firefox, window.location, jquery-waypoints

BLUF: Updating `location.hash` with a scrolled-to element's ID using jQuery Waypoints causes scroll bubbling/stutter in FF, but not Chrome or IE.

Problem:
I'm using [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#docs) to do a few things as a user scrolls through a table with this basic layout:

```
____________________________________________________
| <tr class="category" id="cat1">Category One</tr> |
|   Cell          |    Cell       |   Cell         |
|   Cell          |    Cell       |   Cell         |
|   Cell          |    Cell       |   Cell         |
____________________________________________________
| <tr class="category" id="cat2">Category Two</tr> |
|   Cell          |    Cell       |   Cell         |
|   Cell          |    Cell       |   Cell         |
|   Cell          |    Cell       |   Cell         |
```

One of the things I'd like to do is append the ID of the `.category` row at the top of the viewport to `window.location`. This jQuery works in Chrome 34 and IE, **but in FF 28 it causes a "bubbling" behavior where the browser tries to jump back up to put the element at the top of the viewport even as a user keeps scrolling down**. I've commented out `preventDefault` here because although it fixes the jump in FF, it also stops the script from updating the hash after the first `.category` element is reached. Has anyone run into similar problems with updating the `location.hash` in FF or have an idea of how to fix it?

```
$( '.category').waypoint(function() {
    //strip current hash from window.location
    window.location.hash.replace('#','');
    //store waypoint element's id
    var setHref = $(this).attr('id');
    //set id as location.hash
    window.location.hash = setHref;
    //e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}, { context: 'section' });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a core feature of changing `location.hash`: it scrolls you to the fragment referenced by the hash. There is no getting around it using `location.hash`.

For decently modern browsers you can use [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.C2.A0method) or [replaceState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState%28%29.C2.A0method) to manipulate the URL and navigation history without causing a jump to the newly pushed document fragment.